# Assigning and modifying MySQL query to variable

Tags: mysql

This is my first procedure in MySQL and I am trying to take the ID column from my table, store it into a variable and then add 1 to it and then update the table with the new value. When I call `myFirstProcedure()` it sets all of the id values to 6 rather than increasing each by 1. How do I code this correctly?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE myFirstProcedure()
BEGIN
DECLARE IdValue INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO IdValue
FROM new_table;
UPDATE new_table
SET ID = IdValue +1;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What do you want to do with that stored procedure?

Comment: Note that you have only one variable and many rows. You should better define what you want to do. Do you want to update all IDs in all rows? Do you want to increment ID in some specific row? Do you want to generate a new ID for a new row? Do you want to renumber all IDs for all the rows?

Comment: You store only one ID in your store? Then you told that you do not want to update the ID in all the rows. As I said , you have to define what you want to do and until now I could not hear a description that would make any sense. Can you maybe define what is the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are setting all the values to the same value.  You can do this by incrementing the variable in the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE myFirstProcedure()
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_maxid;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_maxid
    FROM new_table;

    UPDATE new_table
        SET ID = (v_maxid := v_maxid + 1);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Note that `COUNT(*)` will return `0` if the table is empty, so there is no problem with `NULL` values.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, there seems to be syntax error.